# Get card id from Stripe API in PHP

Tags: php

According to the API document of Stripe, I can access the `card id` like this:

```
<?php
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

// Get details from card
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve("cus_xxxxxxxxxxx");
print_r($customer->sources->data->id);
?>
```

But nothing is echo.

Could you please help me?

I following this documentation : https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#customer_object

Comment: `var_dump($customer)` instead, to see everything that came back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A customer can have multiple cards, so `$customer->sources->data` is an array (as you should be able to tell from the square brackets around the value of this property). Therefore, you need to index it.

```
print_r($customer->sources->data[0]->id);
```

And if a customer has saved multiple credit cards, you should loop over it:

```
foreach ($customer->sources->data as $card) {
    print_r($card->id);
}
```

Comment: I wish I could copy and paste this into stripe documentation. They simply assume you have the card id somehow.

Comment: @Ibu You are suppose save the card id to your own database and then use it to retrieve a specific card. https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#retrieve_card

Comment: @Michael That's what we do, but you could also save the customer ID in your DB and retrieve card IDs from Stripe as in this question.

Comment: Nearly 5 years later and the Stripe documentation is still shitty :/